# CMake cant find Boost

Tags: boost, cmake, azerothcore

When configuring, the logs show the following in red, I've included version and OS if it helps.

```
Windows 10
CMake 3.25.1
Boost 1.81.0
Visual Studio 17 2022

CMake Warning at F:/My_Project/Cmake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 (message):
    New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported targets

Call Stack (most recent call first):
    F:/My_Project/Cmake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1507 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
    F:/My_Project/Cmake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2118 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
```

deps/boost/CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)

Boost_DIR = Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG = Directory is correct
...
Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE = Directory is correct

Just to be on the safe side, I added "BOOST_ROOT" and the directory to both "User variables" and S"ystem variables".

Now, I've already used the bootstrap.bat, followed by the b2.exe.  CMake shows the directory for everything else except the BOOST_DIR.  When I click on configure, it still shows these errors.

Comment: Please learn about proper formatting, what is a minimal reproducible example and remove the inappropriate sentences in your post. Lastly I would recommend to you to include additional information, such as what compiler are you using.

Comment: What you show is just the **warning** about Boost version being newer than one against which the current CMake is tested. If CMake cannot find Boost, then it should be an **error message** below. You need to include it into the post too.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/windows-core-installation

> If you get an error that CMake *Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem program_options iostreams regex) (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.70")
>
> - Locate your Boost folder
>
>   - Run the Bootstrap.bat file
>   - Run the b2.exe file

Answer (score 0):

You can try a diffrent version of boost like latest one 1.81
https://netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boost/boost-binaries/1.81.0/boost_1_81_0-msvc-14.3-64.exe
i'm useing this version

don't forget you must edit system variables for this version directory
and don't forget you must use slash / for directory not back slash \ like this:
orginal location: C:\local\boost_1_81_0
on system variables: C:/local/boost_1_81_0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7wvO.png)